# Create Rest Project in SOAP UI using java

Tags: java, soap, soapui

I am able to create SOAP Project and execute associated test case.

SOAP Code Snippet:

```
public String executeSoapTestcase(final SoapUIData soapUIData) throws Exception {
       SoapUI.getSettings().setBoolean(HttpSettings.RESPONSE_COMPRESSION, false);
        final WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
        String response = null;

        final WsdlInterface[] ifaceArray = WsdlInterfaceFactory.importWsdl(project, soapUIData.getWsdlPath(), true);
        if (ifaceArray == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "inside SoapUIService.executeTestcase Binding  not found in the specified WSDL");
        }
        final WsdlInterface wsdlInterface = ifaceArray[0];
        Operation[] wsdlOperations = wsdlInterface.getAllOperations();
        if (wsdlOperations == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "inside SoapUIService.executeTestcase Operations  not found in the specified WSDL");
        }
        wsdlInterface.changeEndpoint(wsdlInterface.getEndpoints()[0], soapUIData.getEndpoint());
        final WsdlOperation operation = (WsdlOperation) wsdlOperations[0];
        final WsdlRequest request = operation.addNewRequest("addRequest");
        request.setRequestContent(soapUIData.getXmlRequest());
        final WsdlSubmit<?> wsdlSubmit = (WsdlSubmit<?>) request.submit(new WsdlSubmitContext(request), false);
        final WsdlResponse wsdlResponse = (WsdlResponse) wsdlSubmit.getResponse();
        log.info("inside utm-soapui-service SoapUIService.executeTestcase Submit status : " + wsdlSubmit.getStatus());
        if (wsdlResponse != null) {
            response = wsdlResponse.getContentAsString();
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Same thing i want to do for REST Project: I want to create Rest Project using wadl and execute test case.

Comment: "... Rest Project using wsdl ..." What? [tag:REST] APIs do not have a [tag:WSDL].

Comment: My Bad : Basically i need to execute Rest Based Test  using SOAP UI  pragmatically using java, i am able to do that for SOAP Test, unable to do the same for Rest Test case. any help will be highly appreciated.                       if possible kindly provide the sample code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void executeRestTestcase() throws Exception {       

    final WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
    final RestServiceBuilder serviceBuilder = new RestServiceBuilder();
    serviceBuilder.createRestService(project,"Your Rest URL");
    final StringToStringMap headers = new StringToStringMap();
    headers.put("Authorization", "Basic **********");
    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
    final RestRequest request =
            (RestRequest) project.getInterfaceList().get(0).getOperationList().get(0).getRequestList().get(0);
    request.setRequestHeaders(headers);
    final Submit submit = (Submit) request.submit(new WsdlSubmitContext(request), false);
    final Response response = submit.getResponse();
    String responseContent = response.getContentAsString();
    log.info(responseContent);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is working fine but by default it is using GET and could not able to find any method to change from GET to POST.
I am trying to send POST request with REST Body and looking for the code for the same

public void executeRestTestcase() throws Exception {

```
    final WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
    final RestServiceBuilder serviceBuilder = new RestServiceBuilder();    
    serviceBuilder.createRestService(project,"http://restapi.adequateshop.com/api/authaccount/registration");
    final StringToStringMap headers = new StringToStringMap();
    headers.put("Authorization", "Basic a93e4973-11f8-4efe-9d22-6edc3d46c186");
    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
    final RestRequest request = (RestRequest) project.getInterfaceList().get(0).getOperationList().get(0).getRequestList().get(0);
    request.setRequestHeaders(headers);     
   ReadJsonAsString redjson = new ReadJsonAsString();
    String testrf = redjson.readFileAsString("");
    request.setRequestContent(testrf);
    RestMethod HttpMethod = request.getRestMethod(); 
    WsdlSubmit submit = (WsdlSubmit) request.submit(new WsdlSubmitContext(request), false);
    final Response response = submit.getResponse();
    String responseContent = response.getContentAsString();
    System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + responseContent);   

     
}
```